# How to install a Kuman 7" Touchscreen with Raspberry Pi

Tags: hardware, touchscreen

New to Raspberry and just experimenting for now.  I bought a Kuman 7" touchscreen and got the display to work, but I am having trouble installing the matchbox touchscreen software.
I moved the software from the CD-ROM that came with the display to a USB memory stick and started following the command-line instructions.
I am getting errors like:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install libfakekey-devlibpng-devautoconflibxft-devlibtoolautomake –y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libfakekey-devlibpng-devautoconflibxft-devlibtoolautomake
E: Unable to locate package –y
```

Do I need to manually move the install files to a specific directory on the Raspbian SD card?

Is there a tutorial on how to install and configure alternative hardware somewhere on the Raspberry web site?
I am guessing what is going on based on my Windows experience...

Also, there is a software image file on the CD-ROM, can that be unzipped to the Raspbian computer and should it install itself?  (my guess is: not).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that matchbox is a standard software which can be installed from the Pi OS repository using `apt-get install matchbox-keyboard`.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a couple of problems with your installation instructions.  First off,

`sudo apt-get install libfakekey-devlibpng-devautoconflibxft-devlibtoolautomake -y`

the `-y` should go before `install`.  This is a flag to say *automatically answer yes to any prompts*, by putting it at the end, it's being treated as a package name to install and thus produce an error when it can't find it.

More importantly, there should be spaces between the package names - for example,

```
sudo apt-get -y install libfakekey-devlibpng-devautoconflibxft-devlibtoolautomake
```

should become

```
sudo apt-get -y install libfakekey-dev libpng-dev autoconf libxft-dev libtool automake
```

Currently it's looking for a lengthy name that doesn't actually exist as an installable package -- which produces an error.

If you get any further errors, it would probably help if you're able to point us to a copy of the installation instructions.

Some googling led me to links

- https://www.amazon.com/Kuman-Capacitive-Display-Raspberry-SC7B/dp

And then to

- https://mega.nz/#F!iI9WjThL!VHRNzC44Cxlx7CjIQQJqBQ

Assuming it's the files at that mega.nz site, I see a few more errors, most notably spaces missing after the `sudo` command further down (*`sudonano`* and *`sudochmod`* should, of course, be **`sudo nano`** and **`sudo chmod`**)